# LRC checksum in Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, checksum

I am trying to convert a C code to Delphi/pascal, but somehow I cannot get it to work, my approach was like this :

```
function CheckLRC(s : PChar) : Char;
var
  sum : char;
begin
  sum := #0;
  while (^s <> #0) do
  begin
    sum := (sum XOR ^s);
    inc (s)
  end;
  result := sum;
end;
```

Original C code was :

```
   Set LRC = 0
   For each byte b in the buffer
   do
     Set LRC = (LRC + b) AND 0xFF
   end do
   Set LRC = (((LRC XOR 0xFF) + 1) AND 0xFF)
```

Hope anyone out there is able to help me, and can confirm this is the correct way to do an LRC checksum ?

Comment: Which version of Delphi? If it's 2009 or later then Delphi `Char` is 2 bytes wide and your C `char` will be 1 byte wide. Also, the Pascal code is completely different from the C. Why?

Comment: -1. Not only will your Delphi code not compile, it's not even close to the sample "C" code you posted (which is in no way even close to being C). Put more effort into actually trying to solve the problem, and if you can't post **actual**, compilable Delphi code and I'll consider removing my downvote.

Comment: @Chris that's not fortran. More like some sort of pseudo code perhaps.

Comment: @Dave, yeah, it's pseudo-code lifted from wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the exact equivalence of this function may be:

```
function CheckLRC(const s: AnsiString): byte;
var i: integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  for i := 1 to length(s) do
    inc(result,ord(s[i]));
  result := (result xor $FF)+1; // or result := (not result)+1;
end;
```

All "and $FF" in original code is unneeded here, since we are using a `byte` as result.

Comment: In your code "and $FF" is needed in case that overflow checking is on.

Comment: @GJ Who on earth will set overflow checking on? I write code with the default compiler settings. But OK, of course, you're right - so you should better add {$OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF} before this function if you really like slow code elsewhere in your application.

Comment: @Arnaud: IMO, everyone should turn overflow checks on, and range checking too. Not only in debug mode, also in release mode. It hardly slows code down (and for 99% of all code, speed is not an issue anyway -- only optimize when you know something is a bottleneck) and gives you great insight and causes exceptions for errors that might otherwise go unnoticed and cause erroneous results. IOW, **only turn them *off* if you know it is ab-so-lute-ly necessary to do that**. Otherwise, don't turn them off.

Comment: @Rudy You clearly don't write the same kind of applications that Arnaud and I do. Debug mode for overflow and range checking, but not for released code.

Comment: @David: I think both should be on at all times, except if there is an exceptionally good reason to turn them off temporarily, for a few lines. It doesn't matter what kind of programs one writes. And yes, also, or especially in release code. I rather have a program that crashes with an error message than one that silently produces false results. The error is merely embarrassing and can easily be fixed, while the false results might get you and your customer in big trouble. Note that 99% or more of application code is not time critical, so there is no need for a premature setting of {$O-,R-}.

Comment: @Rudy Over 50% of my code is time critical. I've never seen a range error result in erroneous results. And I use strong testing to get rid of them before sending code out.

Comment: @David: Ok, so you are the exception. I'd like to know what kind of code is 50% time critical, though. -- I have seen range or overflow errors result in erroneous results, and anyway, such results often go unnoticed. That is the big problem with them, isn't it? I maintain that usually (not in your case, apparently), these checks should be on all the time, also in release code.

Comment: I write FE code. Performance is all. In these days of mobile computing burning clocks cycles checking index arrays consumes battery.

Comment: @Rudy About integer overflow checking, if you know and assume that no overflow will be checked - you will never be wrong. That's how you code in C/C++. Just select the right integer type depending on the context (`integer cardinal Int64 UInt64 NativeInt NativeUInt`) then always guess in your mind what will happen in case of overflow.  This will definitively be safer than waiting for an exception to be raised on the customer side. Then set {$OVERFLOWCHECKS ON} only if you  need it explicitly, since it's the faster way to check for overflows if you need to (e.g. C needs op tricks to do that).

Comment: @Rudy BTW `{$O-}` will turn optimization off, not overflow checking off. This is done by the $Q compiler directive or $OVERFLOWCHECKS IMHO.  ;)

Comment: @Arnaud: I always use the project settings. <g> Anyway, we don't program in C/C++, and just because they lack it, we don't have to turn it off. Sorry, but I think $Q+,$R+ is crucial. Overflow or range errors can happen if we make mistakes (and we all do), and I have said why I think it is important to get an error instead of a silent overflow or range violation.

Comment: @David: If with FE you mean finite elements, I wonder why you use not-so-well-optimized Delphi instead of something more suited and optimized for that task. If not, I don't know what FE means. But this "burning clock cycles checking array indexes consumes battery" is a little over-dramatic, right?

Comment: @Rudy FE is as you understand. We use Delphi to get benefit of rapid development. We hate C++. Low level worker classes use hand assembled 8087 for small benefits. Delphi not actually that terrible. Looking forward to SSE2 on 64 bit.

Comment: @Leonardo For every integer arithmetic, there is a compare and a jump. I think about 200-300% code increase on average. It's not so slow on modern processors, because the jump is always taken and the CPU knows that, but increasing code size may miss L1 caches and pipelining, and therefore is potentially slower for some efficient kind of process.

Comment: @Rudy I don't get what you call "Project Settings" - it's dedicated to a project, so it's no reference. The default IDE settings is Overflow Checking OFF. So I use this settings. I don't have to turn anything off. You are turning something on.

Comment: @Arnaud: you can set such options on the Project Options page, or you can specify them in code, using {$Q+,$R+} etc. I use the Project Options for such settings, and hardly ever use the directives in code, so that is why I was wrong with the $O (instead of $Q) directive.

Comment: @Arnaud: "I think about 200-300% code increase on average." That is rather overdone. It may be the case for one piece of code that does nothing but access arrays, but otherwise that is pure nonsense. Take a typical program you wrote, compile it without the options, note the size, then compile it with the options set, and compare the sizes. You won't see an increase of 200%.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - I think Arnaud is talking about integer arithmetic code.